# Making the first div element posititon:absolute(relative to body) , is making my follow up div to hide under my first div

Tags: css, css-position

When I position:absolute my first div relative to body, the follow up div-element content to hide under the first div, from what I know the follow up div(block element) has to come on the next line. and when posititon:absolute my 2nd element too , It covers my first element.  Can someone explain me what exactly happens for second element if I position:absolute my first element.

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second">
      <div class="d"></div>
      <div class="e"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your first div is position absolute it is brought outside the natural hierarchy of elements. You can now freely choose a position for it. Your second div is now pushed up and is therefore at the same position as the first div was before setting it to absolute.

Divs are by default `display: block;` so they go underneath each other.

You can add `z-index: 5;` (or whatever number) to the second div in order to bring it to the front. And if that's not working add a lower z-index to the absolute positioned element. Keep in mind in order to use z-index you always need to specify the `position:`

What do you actually want to accomplish? I can improve my answer then.

Comment: I'm new to CSS, so just practicing these positions and wanted to know them better. you answered my question perfectly. Thanks for the help !!!